# Question about preposition in the sentence

Tags: grammar

Tell me please what is better to say:

> I want to experience more of smth.

or

> I want to experience more in smth?

Is this sentence grammatically correct or not? How would you say?

Comment: It will depend what you are talking about. Can you provide more detail?

Answer (score 1):

Either could be correct, depending on what you're talking about.

Most of the time, it would be “more **of** [something]”, with [something] standing in for some experience or some opportunity for experiences:

> . . . I want to experience more **of** the world than just my own country . . .
> <sub>Source: [bubearcats.com – Kurth Shares Experiences From Sochi Olympics](http://www.bubearcats.com/index.php/news/show/kurth_shares_experiences_from_sochi_olympics)</sub>

This is usually followed by “the” as it is above, because “of” requires you to name something specific, not just a general feeling or type of experience. Notice the difference between these two statements:

- I want to experience more of **the** joy life has to offer.
- I want to experience more **<s>of</s> [Ø]** joy (in my life).

Other times, you might just be saying that you want to **experience more in general.** In this case, you can follow that statement with anything that makes sense, including something starting with “in”:

- I want to experience more in the future.
- I want to experience more in 2014.
- I want to experience more in life.

The last one is probably [the most common statement of this kind](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+want+to+experience+more+in%22). Of course, you could also say “I want to experience more **of** life” which has essentially the same meaning. You'd just be treating life as either an experience unto itself or as the locus of various experiences.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what smth is, and as a result, this question cannot really be answered definitively.

However

```
'I want to experience more of smth.'
```

Is likely correct

Comment: Without a knowledge of what the something actually is, the question still cannot be answered definitively.